# iOS App Introduction

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

I am looking for framework that I could use from that in my iOS project to introduce my app an show it's feature with something like finger over screen and show that what button do what, what gesture do what and so on.
Is there any framework for that?

Comment: I hope [this is what you are looking](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=introduction)

Comment: I look for something like what you could see in this app first luanch: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boice/id567144441?mt=8

Comment: Voted to close due to being off-topic because you are asking for third-party/off site resources.

Comment: That was just image (with explanation) which get's removed after clicking it... that's it...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found what I need, [Tutorial Lib](https://github.com/kronik/UIViewController-Tutorial)